# Build FFMPEG 1.2 (Code name magic) for android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I'm working on a multimedia project. Where i need to concatenate more than one videos. I found that `ffmpeg concat demuxer` has been added to `ffmpeg fire flower` (version 1.1). Somebody help me out on, how to `builid ffmpeg 1.1 / 1.2` for android?.

I've checked all other alternatives, None succeeded. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264  "Updating Submodules" is a roadmap of what u need to do

Comment: have you tried this - http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg4android/

Answer (score 0):

this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17444442/1865860 and mainly this: https://github.com/dentex/ytdownloader/tree/master/FFmpeg_and_lame_sources should help you.